# Progressbar.js - SVG progress bar not working IE 11,10,9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, svg, progress-bar

I am using this awesome plugin (https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js) for rendering a SVG progress bar arround an object. It works fantastic in Chrome, Firefox, Mozzilla and Safari but IE (all versions) are dumped.

```
circleProgressBar = new ProgressBar.Circle('#progress div', {
                                color: '#48c1ff',
                                strokeWidth: 10,
                                duration: 500
                            });
```

When I use the function for animation:

```
circleProgressBar.animate(1);
```

In all the normal browsers it creates full circle BUT IE has something special: [*click here*](http://honzakopecky.8u.cz/isis/progressbar-ie.JPG)

Interesting fact is that if I open developer tools after the animation is done (in IE) SVG is probably somehow re-rendered and it looks as it should look.

Thank you for your replies in advance.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same problem!

Comment: @swedish_junior_dev Yeah, the solution below worked for me. I am sorry for not marking it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need use strokeWidth < 7. If it more then 7 it won't work in the IE. You can detect browser. For IE use less 7. For other use what you want.

Comment: it works! but thats absolutely insanely stupid! is there a legit reason for this?

Comment: You're a life saver